# Query django model for data from an external source

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

Given a django model...

***models.py***

```
class UserRelationship:
    user_id - IntegerField
    staff_id - IntegerField
    valid_from - DateTimeField
```

...and some logic that retrieves data from an external API.

***api.py***

```
class Approval:
    user_id - Int
    created_at - DateTime
```

With a list of "approvals":

```
approvals = [{'user_id': <user_id>, 'created_at': <created_at>}, ...]
```

I need to find an efficient way to derive "staff_id" at the time of approval for a list of "approval" objects.

I can't think of a way to doing this using django ORM.

I know we can do complex lookups with Q objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

qs = UserRelationship.obejcts.filter(Q(user_id=<user_id>) & Q(created_at__lte=<created_at>))
```

but thats only for a single combination of `user_id/created_at`, how can I do this for a large list (~20k+) of "approvals".

Any help or tips will be greatly appreciated. Many Thanks.

Comment: At the moment your question is too broad. Where do these approvals come from. And BTW, can't you post your actual models instead of this syntactically incorrect stuff?

Answer (score 2):

> Given a list of "approvals" (derived from an external source) e.g
>
> ```
>    approvals = [{'user_id': <user_id>, 'created_at': <created_at>}, ...]
> ```
>
> I need find an efficient way to find "staff_id" at the time of approval for a list of ~20k+ "approval" objects.
>
> i.e for each dict find a matching row where
>
> ```
>    approval.user_id = user_relationship.user_id and approval.created_at <= user_relationship.valid_from
> ```

Efficiency will matter a lot based on your external datasource, indexing, etc.  But for your direct question as to how to formulate your query, the [best place to start is with django.db.models.Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

> If you need to execute more complex queries (for example, queries with **`OR`** statements), you can use **`Q`** objects.
>
> A **`Q`** object (**`django.db.models.Q`**) is an object used to encapsulate a collection of keyword arguments. These keyword arguments are specified as in “Field lookups” above.

```
filters = Q()
for x in approvals:
    filters |= Q(user_id=x['user_id'], valid_from__lte=x['created_at'])
relationships = UserRelationship.objects.filter(filers)
```

And you can get the `staff_id` by looping over the `relationships` queryset.  This example assumes that you have unique `user_id`s in the approvals list so that you can go back and associate the correct approval with the correct staff_id.  If you can have multiples of the same `user_id` in the approvals list, you just have to partition your approvals in such a way that a user_id does not appear more than once in each partition.

```
partitions = []
check_ids = []
for x in approvals:
    current_partition = None
    current_check_id = None
    for partition, check_id in zip(partitions, check_ids):
        if x['user_id'] not in check_id:
            current_partition = partition
            current_check_id = check_id

    if current_partition is None:
        partitions.append(list())
        check_ids.append(set())
        current_partition = partitions[-1]
        current_check_id = check_ids[-1]
    current_check_id.add(x['user_id']
    current_partition.append(x)
```